# Can I import translation from one fb-app to another?

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a facebook application and I have one in "sandbox mode" (my app for testing) and another exactly equal that is production app.

I've been translating one of these applications because I created some Open Graph publications and now I want to import translations I've made to the other application. I've seen a "export" link but I don't see "import" link in the other application.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here from a staging app to production. Did you already find it out?